# Advice needed on C++ file reading for a beginner

Tags: c++, arrays, class, ifstream

I have a file with some text it in like this:

```
 Grey Heights 300 
22 White Road 400
100 Abbey Close 820
```

The first number on each line is the street number, followed by the street name and finally the cost to rent per month.  I am trying to read this information into an array of type class.  I am unable to figure out how to separate and detect the different parts of the sentence.  Has anyone got any experience with sorting text from a sentence into different variables and have you got any tips for me?  Currently I am reading the lines using the GETLINE method which works fine and it seems to discard the whitespace like I wanted it to but I am struggling with some lines of the text file which only show the house name and not the number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class cSquare { //declares a new class called cSquare
public: //declares all members as public
string SquareName; //first and only member of the cSquare class called square name
string getSquareName() const; //class method to output the contents of SquareName
void setSquareName(string); //class method to input into the variable SquareName
friend istream & operator >> (istream & is, cSquare & s); //sets a friend to allow the use of >>
};

// square name set method
void cSquare::setSquareName(string sname)
{
SquareName = sname;
}

//square name get method
string cSquare::getSquareName() const
{
return SquareName;
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const cSquare & s) //friend 

{
os << s.getSquareName() << ' ';
return os;
}

istream & operator >> (istream & is, cSquare & s) //friend 
{
is >> s.SquareName;
return is;
}

int main()
{
string discard;
int i = 0; //counter
const int MAX_SIZE = 26; //declares a constant to store the size of the array - this will not chance 
so it is ok to be a const
ifstream monopoly("monopoly.txt", ios::in); //reads file in as a read only file
if (monopoly.is_open()) //checks if the file is open
{
    cSquare myArray[MAX_SIZE]; //declares the array of the object cSquare class

    getline(monopoly, discard); //allows it to be read line by line 
    string sname; //string to store what I read in from my file

    while (i < MAX_SIZE && monopoly >> sname) //inputs the contents of the file into the string sname
    {
        myArray[i].setSquareName(sname);//stores the string read in into the array
        cout << myArray[i].getSquareName(); //it outputs what is stored in the array here
        i++; //adds one each time to the i counter
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's an unpleasant input format to work with. Can you change it?

Comment: Do you mean the text file? sorry

Comment: @molbdnilo when you say input format do you mean inputting it into an array of objects?

Comment: The text file is your input. The input format is the structure of your text file. If possible, add separators between the fields (e.g. some character that does not occur in the actual data).

Comment: In the text book exercise its say to not change the text file :( is there any other way to do this.  I just want to learn and improve.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ read file CSV" or "c++ read file space separated"  There are already a plethora of questions and answers about this topic.